# Hover button change css of other class

Tags: html, css

In the following html the `.pricing-item` has a border which appears when it is hovered (`.pricing-item:hover::after`). I am trying to set it so that when the button (`pricing-button btn-primary`) is hovered, the css for the `.pricing-item` border is set to '0px;'.

```
<div class="pricing-item">
                <div class="pricing-icon"></div>
                <h3 class="pricing-title">Title</h3>
                <div class="pricing-price"><span class="pricing-currency">$</span>200<span class="pricing-period">/ year</span></div>
                <ul class="pricing-feature-list">
                    <li class="pricing-feature">Feature</li>
                    <li class="pricing-feature">Feature</li>
                    <li class="pricing-feature">Feature</li>
                    <li class="pricing-feature">Feature</li>
                </ul>
                <button class="pricing-button btn btn-primary">Choose plan</button>
```

In css file tried using `~` or `+` to make one class affect the other but just not getting it right. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you mean on hover {border:none};  ?

Comment: There's no approach for doing this explicitly by pure CSS. You might want to look at [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Compass](http://compass-style.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a trick you can do, to achieve what you want.

```css
.pricing-item-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.pricing-item {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 1;
}

.pricing-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 1px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.pricing-button:hover + .pricing-item {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-item-wrapper">
  <button class="pricing-button btn btn-primary">Choose plan</button>
  <div class="pricing-item">
    <div class="pricing-icon"></div>
    <h3 class="pricing-title">Title</h3>
    <div class="pricing-price">
      <span class="pricing-currency">$</span>
      200
      <span class="pricing-period">/ year</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="pricing-feature-list">
      <li class="pricing-feature">Feature</li>
      <li class="pricing-feature">Feature</li>
      <li class="pricing-feature">Feature</li>
      <li class="pricing-feature">Feature</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks LGSon and all the other people that posted their suggestions. I mark this as the answer because it was easier just to create the new wrapper, move the <button> up and then just play with the css to get the look I wanted. Also I preferred to use css than JS to get the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no CSS selectors can go up the dom.. For this you'd have to use JS.

You could add that hover effect on `pricing-item` but not from just hovering on the button within that element.

A simple JS version would be:

```
$('.pricing-button.btn-primary').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).parent().css('border', '2px solid black');
  },
  function() {
      $(this).parent().css('border', 'none');

  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current HTML code, the short answer is : **you can't**.

The reason is : you try to access a parent element with CSS, which is not possible.

```
<div class="pricing-item">
            ...
            <button class="pricing-button btn btn-primary">Choose plan</button>
</div>
```

**You'll have to change something in your HTML**, e.g :

```
<div class="pricing-item">
            ...
            <button class="pricing-button btn btn-primary">Choose plan</button>
            <div class="pricing-item-border"></div>
</div>
```

So it will make things a lot easier :

```
.pricing-item:hover .pricing-item-border { /* Display the border */}
.pricing-item:hover .pricing-button:hover + .pricing-item-border { /* Hide the border */}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.pricing-item.no-border{
 border: 0px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".pricing-button".on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse enter
        $(this).parents(".pricing-item").addClass("no-border");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
        $(this).parents(".pricing-item").removeClass("no-border");
    }
});
```